# Python Logging config: Output trace to file, output log message to console

Tags: python, logging

Given the following logging statement:

```
import logging

...
def ...
    try:
        ...
    except MyException:
        ...
        logger.error("Parsing Error: %s"%(sys.exc_info()[0]),exc_info=True)
```

And the following json configuration:

```
"handlers":{
    "error_file_handler": {
        "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
        "level": "ERROR",
        "formatter": "simple",
        "filename": "../log/errors.log",
        "maxBytes": 10485760,
        "backupCount": 20,
        "encoding": "utf8"
    },
}

"loggers": {
    "my_module": {
        "level": "ERROR",
        "handlers": ["console"],
        "propagate": "no"
    }
},
```

How do I modify this configuration such that the trace output does not output to the console, but rather to the error log?

And, at the same time: the log message string still outputs to the console?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"handlers": {
    "error_file_handler": {
        "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
        "level": "ERROR",
        "formatter": "simple",
        "filename": "../log/errors.log",
        "maxBytes": 10485760,
        "backupCount": 20,
        "encoding": "utf8"
    },
    'console': {
        'level': 'INFO',
        'formatter': 'standard',
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler'
    }
}

"loggers": {
    "my_module": {
        "level": "ERROR",
        "handlers": ["console", "error_file_handler"],
        "propagate": "no"
    }
}
```

Change:

1. `"handlers": ["console", "error_file_handler"]`: write log to both file and console
2. `"handlers": ["error_file_handler"]`: write log to file
3. etc

Comment: So what I am trying to do is split the output: my custom message goes to console, and the trace info goes to the file.

Comment: I'm not clear about custom message. Do you mean log level?

Comment: so, `logging.error("my custom message")` would be the custom message, while `logging.error("",exc_info=True)` would print out only the stack trace. 

If I write, `logging.error("my custom message",exc_info=True)`, then both the custom message and stack trace are output to both the file and the console. 

How do I split this up so that the custom message goes to the console, and the stack trace (which is very verbose) goes to the file?